# LyX not cited error

Tags: bibtex, lyx, citing

I was writing a document and everything was fine, but suddenly I get "not cited" errors when I try to add new citations. I can insert the citation, but it shows not cited!

[image]

I checked everything. The bib file and the style file are there and chosen in the bibliography. I also checked the bib and LaTeX log, but nothing is shown there.

The LyX Version is 2.3.4.3, and I am using basic BibTeX, with `IEEEtran.bst`. I tried different options and styles, but they weren't helpful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Best would be to show us the TeX code Lyx generates for a small example file resulting in your issue. Then people having/using Lyx can copy that code, test that code on the own computer and work with it to catch the error ... Simply help us to help you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing citation style to `[#ID]` solved the issue. 
[image]

It was on `add to bibliogrophy only` before that.